# Is there a defacto standard exception or best-practice way in signalling "invalid input" by exception?

Tags: c++

`invalid_argument` is-a `logic_error`.

Both [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/logic_error) [sites](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stdexcept/logic_error/) indicate something on the line of

> This class `[i.e. logic_error]` defines the type of objects thrown as exceptions to report errors in the internal logical of the program, such as violation of logical preconditions or class invariants.
>
> *These errors are presumably detectable before the program executes.*

**Question:** accepting that the semantics of `invalid_argument` is strictly bound to "programmers' mistake", *is there any de facto standard exception* a program/library/server may use to communicate<sup>++</sup> at **runtime** to an external calling party "the provided input is invalid"?

Does your prev experience show a regular pattern in the use of an "invalid_input" type of exception?

If so, is it standard or does everyone just derive their exceptions as needed?

Notes:

1. clearly, `stdexcept` provides none with the *runtime* semantics. And neither do boost
2. while I know/follow the validation-as-early-as-possible rule, I found frequent enough cases in which input data (originated from a user or not) can be validated only in deeper context: the as-early-as-possible may require matching against a deep context, not available "at the gateway".

---

<sup>++</sup> "to communicate" = have, up in the calling chain (or deep in the stack-trace, if you so prefer), a block like

```
// fwd declaration
void function_facing_dirty_code(struct user_input& data);

void function_facing_the_user(const char* jsonArgs) {
  try {
    struct user_input;
    parse_user_input(json_args, user_input);
    function_facing_dirty_code(user_input);
  }
  catch(invalid_input& ii) {
    // **this** should be a standard error for erroneous input/args/etc
    // treat it by telling the out-of-my-control caller to behave
  }
  catch (std::runtime_exception& e) {
    // tell the caller: sorry, you've done nothing wrong,
    // but I'm having generic runtime troubles.
  }
}

void function_facing_dirty_code(struct user_input& data) {
  try {
    // ... do some work
    // ... do some more work
    // Ahhh
    throw std::invalid_argument("Requested amount over the daily redraw limit");
    // ooops. This will cause a BSoD instead of telling the user.
    // Because std::invalid_argument is a logic error
  }
  catch(std::logic_error& bsod) {
    // log an error, blame the author, snitch it to his boss,
    // then generate a BSoD for the user's delight,
    // because she must NOT see our coding family's dirty laundry
  }
}
```

Comment: Why is your api designed so that people pass in arguments with no way to detect if they're valid or not ahead of time?  If they can detect that in any way, they should be doing so. Failing to do so should throw an exception representing a violation of logical preconditions.

Comment: "These errors are presumably detectable before the program executes." means "it is possible to write code at compile time to detect and prevent these errors from occurring".

Comment: What's the confusion? If you are passed an argument, validate it, and find the validation failed, you have an invalid argument. Who cares why it's invalid? It's the caller's fault for the invalid argument, so it's a logical error in the program. If you raw read some user input into a string, and that string is invalid, then it's your fault for not validating it before using it as an argument. Everything fits.

Comment: @MooingDuck "Why is your api designed so that people pass in arguments with no way to detect if they're valid or not ahead of time?"

Simply because variuos condition cannot be always tested ahead of time - or it's highly impractical to do so.
Imagine a condition of "your membership level doesn't allow you to ask this. Your trial period expired just 3 seconds ago"
The best place to test it is somewhere in the "com::evil_corporate::account_mgmt" module, not in the "com::evil_corporate::be_nice_face".

Comment: @MooingDuck "to write code at compile time to detect and prevent these errors from occurring".

Yes, but I'm asking why there's no standard error signalling *at runtime* "non-compliant input from caller", in which the caller is not supposed the be your buddy in the next cubicle.

Comment: Validation may not be possible/practical in a single point. See my "your trial account just expired", a test which practical consideration dictates need to be performed deep into the calling chain and let it surface as an exception with the message to the user.

Comment: Have you considered that a generic `buddy_I_found_garbage_in_your_input` exception might not be the best way to convey that your trial account just expired?

Comment: @zneak - I'm sure you'll be able to imagine a case of "invalid_args" that can be detected in a context of a system state known only to deeper code. Just try it

Comment: I can imagine the throw, but I can't imagine the catch.

Comment: @zneak "I can imagine the throw, but I can't imagine the catch"

Well the catch is "Even applying faultless logic, one can make an invalid argument - e.g. because one of the premisses is false." Therefore, it is logic an invalid_argument needs to be a runtime_error rather than a logic one :) (but I digress)

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi: "your membership level doesn't allow you to ask this" that's not an `invalid_argument`, that would be some sort of `permissions_exception` which should derive from `runtime_error`, since it doesn't signal some programming error.

Comment: @MooingDuck - ..."that's not an invalid_argument"... mate, surely there are cases in which the validity of the provided input can be verified only in deeper contexts of the code. Does my failure to get you a proper one invalidate my question? Or are you trying to say _"The validity of the parameter values can always be assessed in the method start or early. Any other kind of parameter validation error is not an *invalid arg value*, but is..."_ (what exactly?)

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi: If it doesn't represent a preventable error, it's not a logic_error, it's a runtime_error. If the parameter isn't obviously invalid up front, it's not a invalid_argument, it'd be a XXX depending on why it's invalid.

Comment: @MooingDuck "If the parameter isn't obviously invalid up front"... mmm, again, the case of building on top of 3rd-party libraries; what is "upfront" for the library programmer, may be an obscure place for me, as the consumer of that library (used deep-down in my code). What you say amounts to "write your validation upfront, in the 'gateway' of your code, even if such a code is already implemented in the library you are using" - code bloat, loss of performance, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea behind `std::logic_error` and derived classes is to be a bit like a glorified assert - and in the standard library they are used somewhat like that (think `vector::at` - what kind of recovery do you want to have from an invalid vector index? It just means that the logic is botched, it's just a friendly alternative to UB); also `invalid_argument` is used for something like that, IIRC in `std::bitset`.

But I agree that in general an "invalid argument" kind of exception can derive both from a "logical" or "runtime" error; my main point here is: don't seek much logic where there isn't any.

The whole `<stdexcept>` thing looks like it was jotted down as an afterthought before going to dinner, and then completely forgot. Extremely wide classes of errors are squarely divided into this logic/runtime dichotomy (of disputable value), essentially based on how they are used in the standard library for those that are used; those that aren't used (which should be a convenience for the programmer) are random both in choice (`overflow`/`underflow`/`domain_error` - maybe they were thinking just about mathematical functions?) and characterization (an `out_of_range` is "logic" but an `overflow` is "runtime"? debatable at best).

In short: don't overthink the `stdexcept` ideas - they are vague, disputable and then hammered to fit some needs of the standard library. Derive the exception hierarchy that makes sense for your application from `std::exception` or `std::runtime_error` and be happy with it.

Comment: Well, I can't find any error in you logic - matches the reality so far.
I came back to C++ after years of Java, and I found their expns hierarchy quite common-sensical, in spite of their huge numbers.
Now, seeing "logic_error" and "runtime_error", I sorta expected deep-thought went into the `stdexcept` and the sparsity of it is the result of elevated minds analysing heaps of code and deciding "those are the ones everyone will ever need as foundation to build on". Surprise… not one to tell the user "something wrong with your input" - that's sooo standardly basic. So, worry… what am I missing?

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi: `std::runtime_error` is designed to be derived from. For each category of thing that can be wrong, there ought to be an exception that derives from a standard exception class. It's designed to be pretty rare to actually _throw_ one of the standard exceptions, because there is no set of standard exceptions that could possibly cover most use-cases for most programs.

Comment: @MooingDuck True. However, there are categories of exceptions that are so widely used that worth standardizing - invalid_input at runtime being one of them.

Comment: @MooingDuck Lacking a "standard" one with that meaning means that if I build on top of 3 libs, each one with its own form of "invalid_input", I'll need 3 specialized catchers.  As zneak put it "I can imagine the throw, but I can't imagine the catch".

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi: You should have a catch at each place you need to handle an exception. In general, that should be one per couple functions, regardless of same types or different types.